# LTR in RTL Devices in react native

Tags: react-native, right-to-left

**New Question**

My App is `Left to Right` but When Someone with Arabic Phone open my app, all of Styles  Gets `Right to Left`

**How Can I make My APP Fix Static Left to Right in all languages?**

Comment: you can use modals

Comment: No Sedric use built in Modal. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html

Comment: Glad that helped!

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

Comment: @EnieJakiro No, I can make my photo full Screen, I mean Because my photos are comming from a json or js data automaticaly, how to show each photo in modal? what should I put when my modal opened? because I haven't a specific photo, i have photo with id 1,2,3,4,....

Comment: Use states to change modal content

Comment: @EnieJakiro I Solved my problem with Linking but I like to use modal, Can you see my Question photo Because I Updated my Question and I described more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Added This: `android:supportsRtl="false"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and Solved

Comment: How to control this in iOS? Is there any way?

Comment: there is not `manifest.xml`  in my project. where i search for that?

Comment: it's in your android folder.

Answer (score 8):

You can simply add the following to your app.js or to your firstscreen.js if you are on Expo

```
import { I18nManager} from 'react-native';
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);

export default class <className> extends Component {



}
```