React native FlashList not working on Android in RTL mode
I wish you all doing good!
I am currently working on a react native project, I have very large list, so I've decided to use FlashList... In iOS everything works correctly, in Android in LTR mode there is no issues, but when the application is in RTL mode I got like this:
Screen record: https://imgur.com/a/jNnHNYQ
green background is just for debuging
So the problem is the list item display at first but speedily fade and left a blank screen :/ , also when I remove horizontal the items appears again but vertically
Here is my FlashList component:
  <View style={{ direction: 'ltr', flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}> // I need this list to be always ltr
    <FlashList
      data={quran}
      extraData={focusedVerse} // for highlight
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled
      disableHorizontalListHeightMeasurement={true}
      estimatedListSize={{ width: RW(100), height: RH(100) }}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      estimatedItemSize={windowWidth}
      keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
      inverted={true}
      disableIntervalMomentum
      decelerationRate="fast"
      snapToInterval={RW(100)}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
      removeClippedSubviews={false}
    />
  </View>

and here is renderItem:
  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item }: any) => (
      <View key={item.id} style={styles({ Colors, Paddings }).container}>
        <View
          style={[
            styles({}).topAndBottom,
            { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' },
          ]}
        >
          <CText>{t('quranKarim')}</CText>
          <CText>{t('quranKarim')}</CText>
        </View>
        <View onLayout={handleLayout} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {images.map((val: string, index: number) => (
            <View key={index} style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
              {focusedVerse && focusedVerse.some((val: any) => val.line === index) && 
              (
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: focusedVerse.filter((val: any) => val.line === index)[0].width,
                  height: RH(5.375),
                  top: 0,
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  backgroundColor: '#ffd5b5',
                  position: 'absolute',
                  zIndex: -1,
                  left: `${focusedVerse.filter((val: any) => val.line === index)[0].left * 100}%`,
                  }}
                />
              )}
              <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={1}
                style={{
                  width: '100%',
                  height: RH(5.375),
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                onPressIn={(e) => {
                  pressTimeoutRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
                    const lineVerses = item.chapter.verse
                      .filter((v: any) =>
                        v.VerseHighlight.some((highlight: any) => highlight.line === index)
                      )
                      .map((v: any) => v.VerseHighlight);
                    handlePress(e, index, lineVerses);
                  }, 50);
                }}
                onPressOut={() => {
                  if (pressTimeoutRef.current) {
                    clearTimeout(pressTimeoutRef.current);
                    handlePressOut();
                  }
                }}
                onLongPress={handleLongPress}
              >
                <Image
                  source={val}
                  style={{ width: '100%', height: RH(5.375) }}
                  cachePolicy="memory"
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
        <View style={[styles({}).topAndBottom, { alignItems: 'center' }]}>
          <CText>{item.id + 2}</CText>
        </View>
      </View>
    ),
    [focusedVerse, imageContainerDimensions, images]
  );


FLashList version: 1.6.4 (I tested all new versions with no success)
Expo sdk: 50.0.20
React-nativ: 0.73.6

Thank you for your time!

Do you need RTL mode? If not did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825481/2632709

@RoniCastro I've tried this method but with no success :(

Please include the flash-list version. This may constitute a bug you'd want to post on their issue tracker, though they're not very responsive.
